# Georeferenced TIFF to Google Earth?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, georeferencing, google-earth-pro, arcgis-10.4

I have aerial view images (.TIFF) which I have georeferenced using ArcMap 10.4. What I am trying to do with the images is export them with the georeferenced data attached and import them to Google Earth Pro. What would be the best way to go about this task?

Answer (score 1):

[This Google Earth support page](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148109#opengis) explains how to achieve this. Basically you need to make sure that your imagery is on WGS 1984 projection and follow File>Import steps. You may be asked to create a Super Layer, which will be a KMZ version of your imagery.

Another option is to use [Layer to KML](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/layer-to-kml.htm) tool in ArcGIS. You need to be careful as setting the "Output Image Properties" parameter to have a decent output, though.